# How to get from Bradford to Heathrow Airport T4, London?

Tags: airport-transfer, london, lhr

I've a flight from Heathrow Airport T4 at 14h:00.
What is the cheapest way to get from Bradford to Heathrow Airport T4, 
arrival : before 12h:00?

Comment: Hitch-hike? Or did you have some sort of public transport in mind?

Comment: To answer this, we'd need to know *your* circumstances, as well as the required journey. What's your budget? How many people are you moving? Do you have any luggage? Do you have any accessibility requirements? Do you want to minimise CO2 emissions? Do you have a morbid fear of coaches? etc etc etc

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not the cheapest, but the easiest by far will be to fly. British Airways runs flights from Leeds-Bradford airport to Heathrow (around 1 hour, plus the time to get to the airport), and normally only charges around 60 pound for them.

Other options would include train (eg, East Coast Rail to London King's Cross and then the Tube and/or Heathrow Express to Heathrow, at least about 4 hours) or bus (eg, National Express  Bradford direct to Heathrow, around 7 hours).

Alternatively you could rent a car and drive.

Comment: Of those options the bus is going to be the cheapest.

Comment: Bus will be cheapest, but the 7 hours it takes means that you'll probably need the 2:15am departure, which isn't very sleep friendly...

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend checking your options on transportdirect.info and nationalrail.co.uk . transportdirect.info is very comprehensive and can search across multiple modes of transport (and it works surprisingly well).

If journey time is not an issue, there seems to be a direct coach between Bradford and Heathrow airport (found it through transportdirect). If you have luggage, this may be a particularly good option. Book the ticket in advance on nationalexpress.com. Time table is available here[1](http://www.nationalexpress.com/assets/uploads/pdf/timetables/R240.pdf). Since the journey is direct, you can catch up on sleep in the coach.

Update: transportdirect.info was shutdown, try traveline.info instead (not that good)